# Yii2 disable auto logout

Tags: yii2

How to completely disable auto-logout?
My current config in `web.php`:

```
'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\AdminUser',
            'enableSession' => true,
            'authTimeout' => 18000
        ]
```

I also tried this, but it didn't work (auto logged me out after 60 seconds):

```
'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\AdminUser',
            'enableAutoLogin' => false,
            'authTimeout' => 60
        ]
```

I don't want a user to logout after anytime he is inactive.
I can not find the answer here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html

Comment: what you are looking for is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54210708/yii2-never-logout-idle-or-away-user/54214916#54214916

Answer (score 0):

Just comment the line with 'autoTimeout'

```
'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\AdminUser',
            'enableAutoLogin' => false,
            //'authTimeout' => 60
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable cookie-based login, cause session has a limited time and expired fast.

```
'user' => [
    'identityClass' => 'app\models\AdminUser',
    // this will allow to store auth info in cookie
    'enableAutoLogin' => true
]
```

[yii\web\User::login()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-user#login()-detail) method has attribute $duration

```
Yii::$app->user->login($identity, 60*60*24*365*10); // 10 years
```